# Polynomial having all integral coefficients $P_n(a)=b$ and $P_n(b)=c$ and $P_n(c)=a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let $a,b,$ and $c$ denote three distinct integers, and let $P_n$ a polynomial having all integral coefficients. Show that it is impossible that $P_n(a)=b$ and $P_n(b)=c$  and $P_n(c)=a$.

I started like that :

$P_n$ a polynomial having all integral coefficients, means that:

$P_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\alpha_ix^i$  with $(n,\alpha_i)\in \mathbb{N}^2$

$P_n(a)=b$ and $P_n(b)=c$  and $P_n(c)=a$ means that :

$P_n \circ P_n \circ P_n(a)=a $ and $P_n \circ P_n \circ P_n(b)=b $ and $P_n \circ P_n \circ P_n(c)=c $

can you help me with this ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want $P(a)=b$ or $P(P(P(a)))=b$?

Comment: Thansk for you answer @almagest I want to show that is impossible to have $P(a)=b$ and $P(b)=c $ and $P(c)=a$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $P$ is an integer polynomial, then $x-y$ divides $P(x)-P(y)$ for any integers $x,y$. So $a-b$ divides $b-c$ which in turn divides $c-a$ which divides $a-b$. So all thosen numbers are equal up to sign. It is easy to finish from here.

Comment: yes thanks @Ewan Delanoy that means that $a=b=c$ which is in contradiction with $a,b,c$ there distinct integers